# How do I format JSON date array object using PHP

Tags: php, json

I need to format all the date_of_birth attributes of the JSON array using a PHP foreach loop.

Initial date is in Y-m-d and I need to format them to d-m-Y using PHP only.

I have tried it but maybe I am not doing something right.

```
<?php

// Convert json from objects to array
$characters = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);

//Loop through array
foreach ($characters as $key => $value) {
if (in_array($key, ['date_of_birth'])) {
$oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '1988-08-21');
    $characters[$key]['date_of_birth'] = $oDate->format('d-m-Y');
    }
}

file_put_contents('results_new.json', json_encode($characters));


print_r($characters);



?>

 //JSON data
[
{
    "first_name"    : "Andy",
    "last_name"     : "James",
    "date_of_birth" : "1988-08-21",
    "date_of_move"  : "2000-09-11"
},

{
    "first_name"    : "Laura",
    "last_name"     : "Simmons",
    "date_of_birth" : "1968-04-09",
    "date_of_move"  : "2010-09-05"
},

{
   "first_name"    : "Jeff",
    "last_name"     : "Bridge",
    "date_of_birth" : "1980-02-15",
    "date_of_move"  : "1990-08-08"

}
```

]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the way you check for the 'date_of_birth' key causes problems. I've managed to get everything working in a foreach() loop using $value with a reference. Please try the below:

```
<?php

// Convert json from objects to array
$characters = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);

//Loop through array
foreach ($characters as $key => &$value) {
    if (array_key_exists('date_of_birth', $value)) {
        $oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value['date_of_birth']);
        $value['date_of_birth'] = $oDate->format('d-m-Y');
    }
}

file_put_contents('results_new.json', json_encode($characters));

print_r($characters);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "first_name": "Andy",
    "last_name": "James",
    "date_of_birth": "21-08-1988",
    "date_of_move": "2000-09-11"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Laura",
    "last_name": "Simmons",
    "date_of_birth": "09-04-1968",
    "date_of_move": "2010-09-05"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Jeff",
    "last_name": "Bridge",
    "date_of_birth": "15-02-1980",
    "date_of_move": "1990-08-08"
  }
]
```

Comment: Legend mate. Cheers!!

Comment: @LeoG my pleasure! I've updated the answer with cleaned up code and removed a duplicate line.

Comment: @mkveksas my edit is wrong, I didn't notice the `true` arguments for json_decode. I rollback.

Comment: @Cid I tried to amend the previous edit but didn't notice you submitted a new one! Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
$oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '1988-08-21');
```

With this one:

```
$oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value['date_of_birth']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does work but only partially. 

It formats the first date_of_birth, but does not format the remaining two date_of_births.

Comment: Are you sure? Try deleting results_new.json file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use strtotime() :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($characters);$i++) {
    $characters[$i]['date_of_birth'] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($characters[$i]['date_of_birth']));
}
```

Here date format update to d-m-y

Answer (score 0):

`in_array($key, ['date_of_birth'])` isn't working as you expect. Try this way :

```
$json = '[
{
    "first_name"    : "Andy",
    "last_name"     : "James",
    "date_of_birth" : "1988-08-21",
    "date_of_move"  : "2000-09-11"
},
{
    "first_name"    : "NO DATE",
    "last_name"     : "NO DATE"
},
{
    "first_name"    : "Laura",
    "last_name"     : "Simmons",
    "date_of_birth" : "1968-04-09",
    "date_of_move"  : "2010-09-05"
},

{
   "first_name"    : "Jeff",
    "last_name"     : "Bridge",
    "date_of_birth" : "1980-02-15",
    "date_of_move"  : "1990-08-08"

}]';

$decoded = json_decode($json);

foreach ($decoded as $key => $value)
{
    if (isset($value->date_of_birth))
    {
        $value->date_of_birth = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value->date_of_birth)->format('d-m-Y');
    }
}

var_dump($decoded);
```

Outputs :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'first_name' => string 'Andy' (length=4)
      public 'last_name' => string 'James' (length=5)
      public 'date_of_birth' => string '21-08-1988' (length=10)
      public 'date_of_move' => string '2000-09-11' (length=10)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'first_name' => string 'NO DATE' (length=7)
      public 'last_name' => string 'NO DATE' (length=7)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'first_name' => string 'Laura' (length=5)
      public 'last_name' => string 'Simmons' (length=7)
      public 'date_of_birth' => string '09-04-1968' (length=10)
      public 'date_of_move' => string '2010-09-05' (length=10)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'first_name' => string 'Jeff' (length=4)
      public 'last_name' => string 'Bridge' (length=6)
      public 'date_of_birth' => string '15-02-1980' (length=10)
      public 'date_of_move' => string '1990-08-08' (length=10)
```